# Existing Xamarin projects don't load correctly (needs migration), and VS crashes when creating new project?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

It's been a while since the last time I worked on a Xamarin project (3~4 months), in this time I updated VS 2017 few times, now when I open a Xamarin solution, all three projects (except the portable project) don't load and there is this message "needs migration":
[image]

when I select "Reload project" from the context menu of the project, this shows up:

[image]

When I tried to create a new Xamarin project VS crashes and close:

[image]

In the period I didn't work on Xamarin, I made some ASP.NET Core projects, if the issue has something to do with that!

Can anyone please help me fix this mess?

Sln File: https://gist.github.com/mshwf/0c8989aee135420cb246cfe056aefbf6

Android project file: https://gist.github.com/mshwf/6ca1b1cefcf62e47cf34e1688d372bd2

Comment: Did you try moving these projects to Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: What I feel is that there is a problem with Visual Studio installation . Possible for you to reinstall visual studio all over again ?

Comment: I tried now, and it loaded correctly in VS 2015!

Comment: The same problem happening in two machines!

Comment: I had the very problem and it was because update process was not finished completely. What solved that issue was repairing Visual Studio by running its installer.

Comment: @mshwf Did you get a fix for this?

Comment: I had an experience similar to VahidShir. After I recieved a Visual Studio upgrade, I notice a lot of dependencies started failing for Xamarin projects. I removed all my JDKs and then repaired Visual Studio, it installed the proper JDK and loaded the projects correctly again.